# List all Azure Active Directories I'm either a member or guest user of

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a case where I need to list all Azure Active Directories I'm a member of and those I'm invited as a guest user to. Our application is multi-tenant where each tenant have their own Azure Active Directory, and one user can be invited to access the application as another tenant, and should be presented with a UI to switch between tenants/directories like we can do in the Azure Portal.

The first part can be queried using the Azure Resource Manager API for listing tenants which I'm a member of (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list). The response from this API do not include tenants for which I'm only invited as a guest user to though.

Are there any API's that I can call with an access token to query for all Azure Active Directories I have guest access to?

Btw: I'm able to switch between the directories I'm a member of seamlessly using the ng2-adal library, by explicitly setting the tenant in the ADAL configuration object and invoking login() on the ADAL service.

Update:
The answer to my question is that guests must complete the invitation process by following the link in the e-mail that they receive from Azure Ad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any API's that I can call with an access token to query for
>   all Azure Active Directories I have guest access to?

Of course you can!

For your case, I also test in my lab with an account that federated from on-premise and Succeeded. **So, You it seems like your account is not working in the second tenant.**

You can [**use code grant flow with Azure REST API**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6rx3.png) or implict flow  to get access token with has delegated permissions for your account.

I did a test and succeeded:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but we're not using client credentials flow. The access token is acquired by adal.js / ng2-adal library which use the implicit grant flow (sending response_type=token and no client_secret to AAD). If I log into our application using a Microsoft ID that is a **member** of multiple AAD tenants, the API lists all of them in the response. The user which I've invited into a second AAD tenant as a guest is a federated identity using ADFS on-premises. Can that explain why the guest user relationship is missing from the API?

Comment: @JoarØyen  Actually,the access token gotten from implicit flow should work well as code grant flow. So, is this guest user can be find in that AAD tenant ? I mean that is this guest account in cloud or on-premise only ?

Comment: The user I'm testing with is a member in the tenant that is federated on-premises and invited as a guest user in a second tenant that is cloud only. The API returns the tenant where the user is an actual member but not the tenant where the user is invited as a guest.

Comment: I also test in my lab with an account that federated from on-premises. I can also list all tenants which also contains a second tenant. Can you switch to the second directory with that account via Azure portal or powershell?

Comment: I'm not able to log into the Azure portal using the federated identity. As long as the identity you are testing with is a guest user and not a member in the second directory, it has to be something on our side. I'll check with a colleague to verify in his development environment.

Comment: OK, it seems like your account is not in the second tenant.

Comment: I found the issue. My account was registered in the second tenant but I didn't activate the guest account by clicking the "Get started" link in the invitation e-mail. I did try another federated user and went through all the steps, and then the API returned the expected result.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where i can generate that bearer token?