# Public API to list all Azure AD tenants I am a member of

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

Is there such an public API? For example, in Azure portal I can select which AAD tenant to view Azure subscription from. What is the API to get that list?

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: Not completly. The link at the end of your response lead me to the Azure API to list tenants. However, that list contains only tenant ids, guids. I need something I can display to the user to choose a meaningful name from a list. I presume I could sign in to each tenant and use Graph to get the tenant names that way. Seems long-winded so will try when I have some more time. Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

You can use the [code grant flow with Azure REST API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6rx3.png) or implicit flow to get an access token which has delegated permissions for your account.

Here's an example:

[image]

Source: Similar thread [List all Azure Active Directories I'm either a member or guest user of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49653433/list-all-azure-active-directories-im-either-a-member-or-guest-user-of)